# UI freezes for a second when performing .sink operation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, pull-to-refresh

I'm using custom PullToRefresh to refresh the whole screen when user wants. PullToRefresh performs specific operation but freezes for a second while doing so. When I remove .sink from method that is performed on refresh everything works fine.

Method that causes this bug:

```
private func updateFitnessClasses() {
        if let firstCompany = userCompanies.first {
            updateFitnessClassesInteractor
                .update(companyID: firstCompany.id)
                .combineLatest(fitnessClassesRepository.fitnessClassesSections,
                               fitnessClassesRepository.calendarDayItems)
                .replaceError(with: ((), [], []))
                .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _, calendarSections, calendarRows in
                    self?.fitnessClassesSections = calendarSections
                    self?.calendarRows = calendarRows
                })
                .store(in: cancelBag)
        }
    }
```

Where `fitnessClassesRepository.fitnessClassesSections` and `fitnessClassesRepository.fitnessClassesSections` are `AnyPublisher<[CalendarSection], Error>` constructed elsewhere. I use these two publishers in another method that fires in view's `.onAppear` and UI do not freeze there.
Also `UpdateFitnessClassesInteractor's.update()` looks like this:

```
func update(companyID: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
        fitnessClassCache
            .lastUpdateTimestamp(forCompanyID: companyID)
            .prefix(1)
            .flatMap { self.apiClient.sendRequest(.fitnessClasses(timestamp: $0, companyID: companyID)) }
            .map { $0.data }
            .map { self.fitnessClassCache.updateCache(with: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

There is an API call and then new data is saved to database from which it is later fetched in `fitnessClassesRepository` methods.

Comment: try     .subscribe(on: backgroundQueue)
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)

Comment: @SPatel By saying .subscribe(on: backgroundQueue) you mean .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))? Because XCode tells me there is no such thing as 'backgroundQueue'

Comment: Yes use any background queue

Comment: @SPatel okay. So it seems that `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))` might do the job however when I'm pulling to refresh my app crashed because of `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'` error. So when I'm using background thread to use PullToRefresh and there are Realm actions inside methods perfomed, how to schedule Realm to perform everything inside the same thread?

Comment: You may need to make your Realm object thread safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my `fitnessClassesRepository` publishers - `fitnessClassesSections` and `calendarDayItems` - were performing some heavy calculations synchronous on the main thread so the UI freezed for the time of doing those calculations. Having changed these calculations to be performed on background thread by adding `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.global())` in the proper place and adding `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` in my `updateFitnessClasses` method fixed the problem.

Finally, my `updateFitnessClasses` method looks like this:

```
private func updateFitnessClasses() {
        if let firstCompany = userCompanies.first {
            updateFitnessClassesInteractor
                .update(companyID: firstCompany.id)
                .combineLatest(fitnessClassesRepository.fitnessClassesSections,
                               fitnessClassesRepository.calendarDayItems)
                .replaceError(with: ((), [], []))
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _, calendarSections, calendarRows in
                    self?.fitnessClassesSections = calendarSections
                    self?.calendarRows = calendarRows
                })
                .store(in: cancelBag)
        }
    }
```